# Can't install Vowpal Wabbit Python Wrapper Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, pip, g++, ubuntu-16.04, vowpalwabbit

I'm having trouble with installation of the Vowpal Wabbit Python Wrapper:

```
$ pip3 install vowpalwabbit
```

Error:

```
lto1: fatal error: bytecode stream generated with LTO version 6.0 instead of the expected 4.1
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NztK0.png)

**Note that**:

- `libboost-program-options-dev`, `zlib1g-dev`, `libboost-python-dev` are installed,
- `anaconda boost` is installed.

**System credentials**:
Ubuntu 16.04, Anaconda3 for Python 3.6, g++ 5.4.0.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've got it! My solution is:

1. Download installation packages of gcc-3.4.6 and g++-3.4.6 (people say, this version is ["very close" to 4.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/778794/how-to-install-gcc-4-1-2-on-ubuntu-16-04))
2. Install downloaded packages:

   $ sudo dpkg -i compat-gcc34-3.4.6-ubuntu1204-1_amd64.deb
   $ sudo dpkg -i compat-gcc-34-c++_3.4.6-20_amd64.deb
3. Change the default version of gcc compiler to 3.4.6:

   $ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 50
4. Install the VW Python Wrapper:

   $ pip3 install vowpalwabbit
5. Change the default version of the compiler back:

   $ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5

So, it works for me.